# SSRS print stickers with horizontal layout .NET

Tags: vb.net, layout, reporting-services, report, reportviewer

I have 2 or 3 days I frustratingly tried to print a list of items in the form of stickers filling all the space that becomes available.
This is the result I get:
[image: Only vertical]

And this is the result I want, I need to use the horizontal space.
[image: I want to fill using the horizontal space, like this]

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or examples of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you!

I solved my problem following this tutorial: 
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/mssqlserver/creating-mailing-labels-in-sql/